# When does imwrite() fails

Tags: c++, opencv

Does imwrite fails when the pixel values are of type CV_32FC1. I am trying to write an image in a jpg file but this is not working-:

```
        make_response_mat(hr_lrt,response);

        if (!response.data)                              // Checks input
        {
            cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        while (!imwrite("response.jpg", response))
        {
            cout << "Hari" << response.size() << "\n" << response.at<float>(456954, 4);
        }
```

Here response has the pixel value of type float.

Comment: Only 8 bit or 16 bit images can be written using [`imwrite`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite).

Comment: provide more code and details if possible

Answer (score 0):

Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with 'BGR' channel order). You can use  **Mat::convertTo** to convert the image data type.
e.g.
`Mat res;`
`response.convertTo(res, CV_8UC*)`
`* refer to image channel(1, 2, 3)`